# How to validate if user enter an integer or not in datagridview cell in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, exception

In my windows application Purchase Order Datagridview as follows

[image]

If user enter not a number value in quantity cell in the current row, it will throw an exception.I would like to know how to continue if I press ok button in this error message.I tried following code.**But it will popup this message continuously**.How to solve this.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                double unitPrice = 0;
                int quantity = 0;
                quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index].Value);
                unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[3].Index].Value);
                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index].Value = quantity * unitPrice;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Error " + ex.Message);
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you binding the data to the grid? Have you added the columns manually?

Comment: Unit price,BookName and ISBN_No loaded by using a data reader

Comment: OK. I've posed an answer which should do what you need.

Comment: please find my updated answer just copy paste my solution into ur IDE

Answer (score 0):

Please See this.use int.TryParse

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    double unitPrice = 0;
                    int quantity = 0;
                    int.TryParse(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Enter Your Column Name here"].Index].Value, out quantity))
                    if(!(quantity > 0))
                    {
                     MessageBox.Show(" Error ");
                     return;
                    }
                    unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Enter Your Column Name here"].Index].Value);
                    row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Enter Your Column Name here"].Index].Value = quantity * unitPrice;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Full Running Example to understand Tryparse:-

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = "10abc";
            int result = 0;
            int.TryParse(abc, out result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

How I have tested:-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string abc = "10abc";
        int result = 0;
        int.TryParse(abc, out result);
        if(!(result>0))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Numeric Value");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile?  TryParse needs an out parameter?? This also doesn't suppress the exception that OP had requested.

Comment: Error occurred in tryparse block.It said "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes1 arguments"

Comment: its two now                     int.TryParse(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index].Value, out quantity))

Comment: Please try and let me know @Kith

Comment: I changed it to prevent from an error like this.int.TryParse(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index].Value.ToString(), out quantity); But another error occurred when click the datagrdiview cell.It was "Object reference not set to an instance of object"

Comment: don't use this.int and why you suddenly got this error Object reference not set to an instance of object

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of object.I think the reason for this error is I have to type quantity value in datagridview column manually.So it throw this exception when the quantity column null. Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174242/discussion-between-d-john-anshani-and-kith).